# Why does replacing the content of a block using innerHTML prevent the default behavior of the browser?

Tags: javascript, html

i have contenteditable div
   `<div contenteditable="true" id="editable-div"></div>`

I want to add hashtag functionality to this block using this script:

```js
const editableDiv = document.getElementById('editable-div');
editableDiv.addEventListener('input', function (event) {
  let a = editableDiv.innerHTML;
  if (a.indexOf('#') !== -1) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const editableDiv = document.getElementById('editable-div');
    let a = editableDiv.innerHTML;
    // Save the current cursor position
    const selection = window.getSelection();
    const range = selection.getRangeAt(0);
    const startContainer = range.startContainer;
    const startOffset = range.startOffset;
    // Change the contents of the block
    a = a.replace(/#(\w+)/g, '<a href="#">#$1</a>');
    editableDiv.innerHTML = a;
    // Restore the cursor position
    const newRange = document.createRange();
    newRange.setStart(startContainer, startOffset);
    selection.removeAllRanges();
    selection.addRange(newRange);
  }
});
```

```css
#editable-div { height:100px; background-color:grey; }
```

```html
<div contenteditable="true" id="editable-div"></div>
```

Why does the cursor always go to the beginning after changing the content of the block? How can this be fixed? event.preventDefault(); doesn't work. And restoring the cursor position doesn't work.

Comment: Your script repeatedly replaces every # on every keystroke after the first '#' is entered and places the cursor inside the new `a` element which is not editable.

Comment: And you're re-declaring `const` variables inside your `if` for no reason.

Answer (score 0):

After the manipulation of `editableDiv.innerHTML`, the document object model inside the `<div>` is rebuilt, and the `#text` node that was the `range.startContainer` no longer exists. It has been replaced with a fresh `#text` node.

It works if you determine the *position* of the start container inside the `<div>` and set the range start to the *corresponding* container after the rebuild. In the simple example below, the position is just the number of the child element inside `<div>`. But it can become more complex if the `<div>`'s content contains nested HTML tags.

```js
function f() {
  var div = event.target;
  var {
    startContainer,
    startOffset
  } = getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
  var pos = document.evaluate(
    "count(preceding-sibling::node())",
    startContainer, undefined, XPathResult.NUMBER_TYPE
  ).numberValue;
  div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML.toLowerCase();
  startContainer = document.evaluate(`node()[${pos + 1}]`,
    div, undefined, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE
  ).singleNodeValue;
  getSelection().setPosition(startContainer, startOffset);
}
```

```html
<div contenteditable oninput="f()">Above the line
  <hr>Below the line</div>
```

(Instead of determining the *position*, one could place all text in elements (such as `<span>`) that can be identified by their `id`. But that does not cover cases where users can create new elements, for example, add `<li>` elements to a list.)

Comment: how can i fix it?

Comment: You should incorporate the ideas from my snippet, especially the `var pos = document.evaluate(...)` and the `startContainer = document.evaluate(...)` into your code.

Comment: I've been struggling with this problem for four days now and I just can't seem to solve it. It would be great if you could help me out. I'm sure you know how hard it can be when a task gets stuck.

Comment: Since your use case involves generating new `<a>` elements, it is rather more complex, and StackOverflow is not a free coding service. The purpose of my answer was to explain the problem (rebuilding of the DOM) and how it might be overcome.

Comment: I understand that StackOverflow is not a free coding service. How much do you want to resolve my problem?